Way to fetch the information of one Power Automate flow instances which are nearing Time-Out and re-trigger them using second flow
Since the workflow instance expires after 28 days, we want to either extend the timeline of the workflow that are expiring or re-initiate the workflow. What are the various ways we can achieve this? We don't want to use any additional column in SharePoint library and neither we can use premium connectors.

What’s the trigger on your workflow?
